# How to set location for Angular app in dev mode where index.html is different location than root

Tags: angular, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to 'quickly' deploy my Angular app in dev mode to my digitalocean droplet - the problem is: 
***Every file in the node_modules folder is throwing a 404 error*** except of course the bootstrap and jquery cdn

I believe it's because the node_modules folder is in the parent folder to the index.html file - How would I setup my nginx default file location for this app?

Here's my current setup

app folder structure

```
/Root/ 

|- node_modules/ 

|- src/ 
 
    |- index.html 

    |- app/ 
         | - main.ts
```

NGINX default file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name xxx.xx.xx.xx;


    location /randomquote {
        alias /var/www/html/randomquotegen/ ;
        try_files $uri/src/index.html $uri/src/index;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dev mode it's likely that you would be running something like webpack that would `npm start` a small server on port 4200, where in production you would probably just have a `dist/` folder, and would just need a server for that static content.  I would probably recommend a build strategy rather then putting that weight on your prod server,  but if you were to, you would npm install all of the dev dependencies,  `npm start` the dev process and proxy nginx to it with something like:

```
location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```